# How can I limit the number of photos my aiogram bot sends

Tags: python

I am writing a bot on iogram and, as planned, it should receive photos from users and send them to my group. I have implemented this but for some reason my bot is sending multiple instances of the same photo. I'm guessing it's stuck at the await bot.send_photo line, but I don't know how to fix it.
Here is a piece of code that is responsible for this

```
@dp.message_handler(Text("Загрузить фото"))  
async def func5(message: types.Message):
    if message.chat.type == "private" and message.from_user.language_code =='ru':
        await message.answer('Отправьте мне фото и, после проверки, оно будет загружено в PofTW') 
        @dp.message_handler(content_types=['photo'])
        async def photo_handler(message: types.Message):
            photo_id = message.photo[-1].file_id
            answer_user_name = message.chat.username
            photo_caption = str('Автор фото - ') + str(answer_user_name) 
            await bot.send_photo(chat_id='' , photo=photo_id , caption=photo_caption , protect_content=True)
```

I tried to write a return at the end of the if loop, but soon came to the conclusion that the bot was stuck on the await bot.send_photo line and I don’t know how to fix it, Google didn’t help (

Comment: I already solved it, I just had to add a check if message.chat.username != None and it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I saw that you solved the problem, but I want to tell you and people who who will face this problem in the future that there is a `Finite state machine` in aiogram ([you can read more in the documentation](https://aiogram-birdi7.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/finite_state_machine_example.html)) with which you do not need to use nested functions. Also aiogram has a `[BoundFilter][2]` class, and with inheritance you can create your own filters to check private chat

```py
    from aiogram import types
    from aiogram.dispatcher import FSMContext
    from aiogram.dispatcher.filters import Text, BoundFilter
    
    from loader import dp, bot
    
    
    # filters.py
    class IsPrivate(BoundFilter):
        async def check(self, message: types.Message):
            return types.ChatType.PRIVATE == message.chat.type
    
    
    # handlers.py
    @dp.message_handler(IsPrivate(), Text("Загрузить фото"))
    async def func5(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
        if message.from_user.language_code == 'ru':
            await message.answer('Отправьте мне фото и, после проверки, оно будет загружено в PofTW')
            await state.set_state("sending_photo")
    
    
    @dp.message_handler(content_types=['photo'], state="sending_photo")
    async def photo_handler(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
        photo_id = message.photo[-1].file_id
        answer_user_name = message.chat.username
        photo_caption = str('Автор фото - ') + str(answer_user_name)
        await bot.send_photo(chat_id="needed_id", photo=photo_id, caption=photo_caption, protect_content=True)
        await state.reset_state()
```

Comment: Yes, I think it optimizes my code well